# InvalidCertificateException when uploading entities to google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload entities batch to my google app engine datastore

I'm following instructions from here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

I'm getting error: `fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host my-app.appspot.com returned an invalid certificate (hostname mismatch): {'notAfter': 'Mar  6 00:00:00 2014 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.appspot.com'), ('DNS', '*.feelinsonice-hrd.appspot.com'), ('DNS', '*.tap-nexus.appspot.com'), ('DNS', '*.withgoogle.com'), ('DNS', 'appspot.com'), ('DNS', 'withgoogle.com')), 'subject': ((('countryName', u'US'),), (('stateOrProvinceName', u'California'),), (('localityName', u'Mountain View'),), (('organizationName', u'Google Inc'),), (('commonName', u'*.appspot.com'),))}`

My python version is 2.7.5 so I dont think I have to install any ssl addon, descrbed here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=pl&csw=1#rpcssl

My command is:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=https://my-game.appspot.com/remote_api --filename entities.csv --kind=MyEntity -e myemail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by deleting ceacerts.txt and ultrafetch_cacert.txt files from app engine sdk:

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources
/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/
```